# How to get a number from inside a script tag?

Tags: php, string, session-storage

I have this php variable :

```
$temp = '<script>document.write(sessionStorage.login_condetion);</script>';
```

When I echo the value of `$temp` it gives me a number for example `1` and when I use `gettype`  it tells me the type of `$temp` is string. I want to use the value of the `$temp` as a condition in if clause but it does not work no matter how I change it for example I tried all the following cases :

```
if($temp == 1){}
if($temp === 1){}
if($temp == '1'){}
if($temp === '1'){}
if($temp == "1"){}
if($temp === "1"){}
```

I do not know why it is not working in the if clause ? could it be because `$temp` has `<scritp>` tag ? and if it is how could I extract the value that I want it as a number ?

PS: I try to cast as following:

```
$temp1 = (int)$temp;
```

But it does not work if the value of $temp is one it gave me after casting a zero.

Comment: show `var_dump($temp)`

Comment: @HaukurHaf no it'll work

Comment: You can't mix php and JavaScript like that. See the 50000 other questions that make the same false assumption. You need ajax to pass data from client back to server.

Comment: "When I echo the value of $temp it gives me a number for example 1" -- no, it doesn't. Its the string you set it to.

Answer (score 0):

Yours $temp variable is just a regular string.

But when you echo it on a page, the javascript engine will evaluate it and add **1** to the **DOM**, so it seems like the value of it is **1** but actually it's really not.

Comment: I know that but I want to make this value a real value real `1` not just a result of evaluation of javascript engine

Comment: You're not supposed to use javascript in php... your thinking is bad in this situation. Just send data to PHP with Ajax for example